# How do I create datagrid with filter in first row?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I want to use this datagrid for different model. I use ItemsSource for add items and  generating columns.
For example I added photo.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUJLb.jpg)

### View

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
       
        string[] categorys = { "person", "car" };
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            category.ItemsSource = categorys;
        }



        private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (category.SelectedItem)
            {
                case "person":
                    ViewModel.viewModelPerson model = new ViewModel.viewModelPerson();
                    this.datagrid.ItemsSource = model.MyPerson;
                    break;
                case "car":
                    ViewModel.viewModelCar car = new ViewModel.viewModelCar();
                    this.datagrid.ItemsSource = car.MyCar;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

### Model Car

```
class Car
    {
        private string name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }

        private string model;

        public string Model
        {
            get { return model; }
            set { model = value; }
        }
        public Car(string name,string model)
        {
            this.model = model;
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
```

### ModelPerson

```
class Person
    {
        private string name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }
        private string last_name;

        public string LastName
        {
            get { return last_name; }
            set { last_name = value; }
        }
        private int age;

        public int Age
        {
            get { return age; }
            set { age = value; }
        }
        public Person(string name , string lastName, int age)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.last_name = lastName;
            this.age = age;
        }

    }
```

### viewModelCar

```
 public List<Car> MyCar
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public viewModelCar()
        {
            createCar();

        }
        void createCar()
        {
            MyCar = new List<Car>();
            MyCar.Add(new Car("toyota", "corolla"));
            MyCar.Add(new Car("skoda", "octavia"));

        }
```

### viewModelCode

```
class viewModelPerson
    {
        public List<Person> MyPerson
        {
            get; set;
        }
        public viewModelPerson()
        {
            createPerson();
        }
        void createPerson()
        {
            MyPerson = new List<Person>();
            MyPerson.Add(new Person("Alex", "Koval", 12));
            MyPerson.Add(new Person("Kate", "Bobik", 25));
            MyPerson.Add(new Person("Robin", "Gude", 231));
        }
    }
```

In result I got
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiJ6l.jpg)

When a user selects a category, the content changes in the grid.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5h7V.jpg)

If I will have many data in the dataGrid, it's bad for the user. This is why I want to add a filter similar to the image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUJLb.jpg)

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! While many of us would love to help you, we will need you to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As your question is now, we cannot help you. Please include the code that you have tried and how it differs from what you expected.

Comment: I added cades and image. Help me please

Comment: That is not filter actually. That is combobox type column in datagrid. Filters are at the top of the column.